# Why are aqueous solutions included in the equillibrium constant but liquids are not?

Tags: equilibrium

I understand solids are insoluble and will just sit at the bottom of the vessel so we don't include them.

But I am confused as to why aqueous solutions are used in the equilibrium equation but liquids are not.

E.g. for the reaction:

[image: Reaction]

The equilibrium constant is:
[image]

Why isn't **H20 (liquid)** included in the equilibrium constant yet **KCl (aq)** is?

Thank you

Comment: An example would help.

Comment: In the example you give, water would be excluded because it is the solvent of HCl and KOH (both are aqueous). Any change in water then, from the equilibrium, would be insignificant.